# how can I remove dynamically added li in ul using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

how can I dynamically remove li when click event is trigger,because I want to load new li's.

I tried something like this `$(".wrapper-n ul").empty();` but is not working.it will continously adding new li.

Thank you in advance.

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            ...
            ....
            ...
            success:function(data){
                        for (var id = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var dynamicli = '<li class="">' +
                        '<img src="path/to/image" class="_xy">' + data[i].name + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user oncho"></i>' +
                        '<span class="myspan" id="' + data[i].id + '></span></li>';
                        $('#myullist').append(dynamicli);
                    }
             }

        });

    $('#myullist').on('click', '.oncho', function () {
        var id = $(this).find('span').attr('id');
        $(".wrapper-n ul").empty();
            $.ajax({
                ...
                ...
                success: function (data) {

                    for (var id = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var dynamicli = '<li class="">' +
                                '<img src="path/to/image" class="_xy">' + data[i].name + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user oncho"></i>' +
                                '<span class="myspan" id="' + data[i].id + '></span></li>';
                                $('#myullist').append(dynamicli);
                    }

                }
            });
    });
});
```

//index.html

```
 <div class="wrapper-n">

    <ul id="myullist"></ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT: I fixed I used wrong selector. Thank you for helping me.**

Comment: What about it isnt working? Are the old li's still there after the `.empty` call? Also your for loop is `for (var id = 0; i < data.length; i++)` did you mean to have `var i = 0`?

Comment: And why do you have a the for loop at the beginning? There is no `data` variable defined when that gets executed you are likely erroring out, have you looked at the console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html('')` , This will basically remove your all li's infact your ul will become empty:

```
$(".wrapper-n ul").html('');
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @Dropout is it fine now ??

Answer (score -1):

Use the  `.remove()` method in Jquery.

Comment: this will remove the entire element.

Comment: Thats whats to be achieved right? Remove the old `li` completely and then  append new `li`'s?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Can you explain why Varun's answer and mine are wrong that we deserve a down vote? Have you even understood the grammar of the question? which we just basically answered literally "elements.remove(); " Jemz didn't even mention that the whole element shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Try $(".wrapper-n ul").children('li').remove();

Comment: I dont remember the context of this question, But the one thing I noticed is that, $(".wrapper-n ul").empty() & $(".wrapper-n ul").children('li').remove(); will have the same effect.  I didnt downvote your answer though.